# I2C - Certain Targets not Pulling the Lines down fully

Tags: i2c, texas-instruments, pulldown

I have a large number of boards deployed with a TI CC3200 microcontroller and a variety of sensors for an industrial monitoring application. I have been having an issue for some time now, on some of the boards, where an infrared temperature sensor, TI's TMP007, cannot be read from. This includes any manufacturer/device ID registers. They communicate via I2C, and there are 10k pullups on both lines.

I have been looking at the lines on a scope, and found that when communicating with the TMP007 the voltages are only pulled down about half as much as when communicating with some of the other, working, I2C sensors. It still seems like it meets the I2C spec at least though, and the TMP007 appears to ACK when I write its manufacturer ID register to it.

Has anyone had similar issues before where different devices are pulled down to different levels, and what possible causes this could have? For instance, could it be a problem with the hardware or could another I2C device be trying to drive the lines at the same time?

---

I believe Ali Chen has rightly pointed out a power supply starvation issue, switching off some of the other I2C sensors when reading from the TMP007 appears to have solved the issue.

Comment: What additional information can you supply, e.g.: Schematic, (at a minimum, showing everything on the I2C bus and power rails for the I2C devices) and those scope images? Have you tried "problem" TMP007 sensors on different I2C master (e.g. different make of MCU or Bus Pirate etc.) to see if the I2C signal behaviour, when viewed on a scope, follows the TMP007 or stays with the CC3200? You mentioned "for some time" and "on some of the boards". That's worrying. Why only some of the boards - what's different between affected & unaffected boards? And what changed just before this problem started?

Comment: What is operating frequency of your I2C bus?

Comment: The board is TI's CC3200 SensorTag, whose schematic can be found here http://www.ti.com/tool/cc3200stk-wifimk#Technical%20Documents. The operating frequency is 400kHz. I was just about to buy a Bus Pirate actually to test that. Yes, it is an issue that often comes and goes for a given sensor, and has never affected most of the boards. I have been unable to come up with a procedure that reliably reproduces the issue. Also, it seems to happen only under battery power, not if I power them via USB.

Comment: (1) Could you post the oscilloscope screenshot of the I2C waveforms?  (2) You've mentioned industrial monitoring.  Are the I2C slave devices connected through cables?  If so, then how long are the cables?  (3) Is it possible that you have more than one set of pullups?  This may happen if the pull-up resistors are on the sensor boards, and there are multiple sensor boards (similar situation [described here](http://makersconfidential.blogspot.com/2015/10/i2c-pull-up-resistors-on-modules-and-breakout-boards.html)).

Comment: Then you obviously have some power supply starvation somewhere along the bus. Do you have a sizable de-coupling cap at each sensor IC?

Answer (score 1):

I2C has a very relaxed idea of what can be received as a low signal. If a transmitter tries to exploit this and not drive down to the typically 0.5v that's easily possible with any normal driver, it might just get it wrong.

This 'sloppy low' is exploited in devices that are opto-isolated. It's used to avoid hanging the bus. If the device sees the line low, is it because the bus is being driven low, so it should be repeated into the device, or is the device driving it low, in which case it should not drive the bus? This can't be done from a state machine in the device, as the bus could go low at any time. The solution many devices adopt is to expect the bus to be driven down to a decent low voltage, but only drive the bus to a sloppy low, and to sense the difference carefully.

Obviously this approach slashes noise margins, and may not work with other devices that are technically compliant, but do not have generous over-design.

I've not put any specific voltages in here because, if you're going to try to understand or use this technique, you need to get the official specification and read it to the last footnote.

Answer (score 0):

One easy option would be to substitute higher valued resistors (try 22k maybe).  If one of the devices is having a a hard time pulling the line low, it could make it easier on it if the line wasn't as strongly pulled high by the pullups.

Comment: 22k will likely have a difficulty operating at 400 kHz.